# ¿Cómo puedo añadirle un v-tooltip a mi botón usando vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Estoy usando la librería https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify en un proyecto que estoy realizando, pero al intentar añadirle un tooltip a un botón que es el activador de un menú, no funciona el tooltip. Me imagino que sea por los slots.

Este es un ejemplo del tooltip funcionando perfectamente.

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
    <v-btn
            slot="activator"
            color="secondary"
            dark
            small
            flat
    >
        Secundario  - {{ stheme }}
    </v-btn>
    <span>Color Secundario</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Ahora esto es lo que que tengo en mi codigo actualmente:

```
<v-menu offset-y>
    <v-tooltip bottom>
        <v-btn
                slot="activator"
                color="secondary"
                dark
                small
                flat
        >
            Secundario  - {{ stheme }}
        </v-btn>
        <span>Color Secundario</span>
    </v-tooltip>

    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
                v-for="(item, index) in themes"
                :key="index"
                @click="changeTheme(item, false)"
        >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Cuando no tenia el tooltip el codigo se veia de esta manera:

```
<v-menu offset-y dense>
    <v-btn
            slot="activator"
            color="secondary"
            dark
            small
            flat
    >
        Secundario - {{ stheme }}
    </v-btn>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
                v-for="(item, index) in themes"
                :key="index"
                @click="changeTheme(item, false)"
        >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Este es un link de la documentación de vuetify donde pueden ver como se agrega un menú a un v-btn https://vuetifyjs.com/es-MX/components/menus

La idea que me hago es que antes del tooltip yo establecia el `v-btn` con el `slot="activator"` y como estaba dentro del elemento `menu`, este pasaba a ser el que activaba el menu al hacer click, pero al estar ahora dentro de un `tooltip` no sabe cual es el que debe desencadenar esta acción. Si le pongo al `tooltip` `slot="activator"` no funciona tampoco. Que podra hacer para que me funcione el `tooltip` y a la vez me muestre el menu al hacer click sobre el `botón`. No quisiera hacer un dialog. Que me recomendarian????

Comment: la consoloa aparece limpia? probaste poniendo el boton sin nada, a ver que pasa? digo, para andar eliminando problemas de a uno...

Comment: la consola no tiene errores, y el boton no despliega el menu.

Comment: pero el boton esta dentro del menu? algo no me cuadra...

Comment: mira voy a editar la pregunta para que veas el codigo del boton dentro del menu y que funciona

Answer (score 1):

Buscando un poco encontré en la documentación de vuejs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html que podia usar la etiqueta template para solucionar mi problema:

El código seria este:

```
<v-menu offset-y>
    <template slot="activator">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
            <v-btn
                    slot="activator"
                    color="secondary"
                    dark
                    small
                    flat
            >
                Secundario  - {{ stheme }}
            </v-btn>
            <span>Color Secundario</span>
        </v-tooltip>
    </template>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
                v-for="(item, index) in themes"
                :key="index"
                @click="changeTheme(item, false)"
        >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Sorry las molestias, lo dejo aqui por si a alguien le puede servir en un futuro.